# Is there a way to use optional chaning in qooxdoo?

Tags: qooxdoo, optional-chaining

I use qooxdoo 6.0 version.
Optional chaing is a very useful feature, is there a way to use it in qooxdoo?

Comment: Could you add some examples of code to you question body?

Answer (score 2):

No the python compiler do not support the new syntax. You have to switch to the new node based compiler in version 7